# WeakRefence's Target not cleaned

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, weak-references

I'm preparing for MS exam `Programming in C# ExamRef 70-483` and reading book with the same name. There is chapter about using `WeakReference` and following example:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

class Program
{
    static WeakReference data;

    static void Main()
    {
        object result = GetData();
        GC.Collect();
        result = GetData();
    }

    private static object GetData()
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            data = new WeakReference(LoadLargeData());
        }
        if (data.Target == null)
        {
            data.Target = LoadLargeData();
        }
        return data.Target;
    }

    private static object LoadLargeData()
    {
        return new Bitmap(20000, 20000);
    }
}
```

The only change I've done is `LoadLargeData()` implementation, in the book there is `LoadLargeList()` without implementation.

The problem is, that after invoking `GC.Collect()`, my `data.Target` is never `null`. How can I force GC to really collect this `WeakReference` data?

Comment: Compile application in release mode (with optimizations enabled), run without debugger attached (so add `Console.WriteLine("target is null")` in respective if branch to verify it's null).

Comment: Perfect, works!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131389/17034

Answer (score 0):

As **Evk** mentioned in comment, running app in release mode without debugger attaches is the right answer, than garbage collection works as expected.